# download excel using powerbi on clicking button in webapp

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-paginated-reports

In app,click the download button the data will be downloaded as excel using powerbi or paginated report.User send fromdate and todate parameters the excel contain records between dates.It is possible excel straightly download using powerbi and paginated report
Its is possible to download excel using powerbi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.